# IFC files lost their texture / colors after conversion to 3D format

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Starting a few days ago (Jan 10, 2018 to be really accurate...), IFC files converted to SVF format (using Autodesk Forge or directly uploaded to A360/BIM360) have [lost their textures/colors and turned into dark grey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMd19.png).

Is it related to some (new) option in the viewer? or is it due to the conversion process itself which has been somewhat modified?

I have tried the same process with a Revit file (*.RVT), and the colors are preserved, so it might be related only to non-native files (just guessing).

The visualization of IFC files has worked very nicely for more than a year now, so it's a bit frustrating that the quality of the IFC rendering has been so much degraded in the recent days.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a known issue logged as `NW-54041` in our internal case system. According to our engineering team, they have updated the IFC translator recently, maybe there is something changed after this upgrading.

It might take times to figure out what happened to this issue. You can track updates on this issue via sending the issue id to `forge.help@autodesk.com` in the future.

Apologies for any inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for more information: Forge developers are currently [as of Jan 24, 2018] investigating the issue, as mentioned here:

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-ifc-issues